# Real quadratic fields-infinitely many fields

Tags: abstract-algebra

How to prove that there exists infinitely many real quadratic field $\mathbb{Q} \left( \sqrt{d} \right)$. I don't how to prove it.

Answer (score 0):

Choose for example $\;d=p\;$ a prime. Then there are infinitely many different quadratic fields of the form $\;\Bbb Q(\sqrt p)\;$ since each of them is a simple extension for the polynomial $\;x^2-p\;$ .

Comment: How does the fact that $\mathbf Q(\sqrt p)$ is a simple extension for the polynomial $x^2-p$ imply that the fields $\mathbf Q(\sqrt p)$ are distinct as subfields of $\bar{\mathbf Q}$?

Comment: @JohannesHuisman Thank you. Who said that implied this? The asker still has to prove that for different primes the fields in my answer are different (not even isomorphic as fields)...but I think that's pretty simple. The idea is there for the asker to use it...or not.

Comment: "Who said that implied this?" Well, the word "since" in your answer made me wonder whether you had some argument here that I do not see.

Comment: @JohannesHuisman Nop, only the basic idea for the asker to develop it. I've have the whole proof, though.